Error Code 500: Authentication Backend Unknown Error in Firebase/Google Cloud Integration
I'm working on a project where I need to send notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). I have set up Firebase Authentication to authenticate users and obtain an ID token. Then, I use this ID token to generate an access token via Google Cloud's Security Token Service (STS).
My setup and process are as follows:

Firebase Authentication:
Users can sign in using Google Sign-In, email/password, or anonymously.
I successfully retrieve an ID token after user authentication.

Security Token Service (STS):
I exchange the Firebase ID token for a Google Cloud access token.
The token exchange process seems to work fine without any errors.

Sending FCM Notification:
I use the obtained access token to send a notification via FCM API.
My request to the FCM endpoint looks like this:


https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/messages:send
header:
{
 'Authorization': 'Bearer $accesstoken',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

body:
{
  "to": "d7rAtvD7RRqHZ6WYNVZIHt:APA91bEIqwNNpHm65PIEpoCwQ_2Dp7bFWW6YO3-Eq_z8Sxv_x2zeFHFpahbop1A-ofVdZrw7dacVeujG50099hEWtj216zzXYU3J-Gg4KPRXIzygMK-HBQN-YIL9ETEollZV8UvL8Iln",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Test Notification",
    "body": "This is a test notification."
  }
}

However, when I send the notification, I receive the following error response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Authentication backend unknown error.",
    "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
}



I authenticated users with Firebase and obtained the ID token successfully.
I used the Firebase ID token to request an access token from Google Cloud's STS, which worked without any issues.
I used the obtained access token to make an API request to the FCM endpoint to send a notification.
I expected the notification to be sent successfully without any errors.

The audience for the Workload Identity Pool provider is set to //iam.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/POOL_ID/providers/PROVIDER_ID.

What could be causing the "Authentication backend unknown error" when sending a notification via FCM?
Are there any additional configurations or common pitfalls I might be missing in the setup for FCM or Google Cloud access tokens?
How can I further debug or trace this error to find the root cause?

